# BottomNavigationMenu icons with gradient color in android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I cannot make my BottomNavigationMenu icons gradient when selected, I have tried almost all the ways, for example using selector drawables, itemIconTint and etc. but I cannot get what I want. I need to get
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgaJR.png)
I do not in fact have this color among my colours.
Can you please help me to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

I have tried almost all the ways, for example using selector drawables, itemIconTint and etc. but I cannot get what I want. When I use gradient color as the drawable file for the icon tint I get
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uENA.png)

Comment: can you show your work and how exactly it is not working?